# When getting the height of a textBlock it says the same number no matter the actual height

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a WPF chat program and the way I want to display the messages is something like this ([screenshot of how I have it now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC8ta.png)) :

```
Sent Message
                      Received Message
Sent message2
                      Received Message
```

---

**What I'm doing:**

A Scroll Viewer with a grid inside and inside the grid 2 stackpanels, one for the left one for the right.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrlViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Width="472" Margin="10,10,0,67" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Grid x:Name="ScrollViewerChild">
            <StackPanel x:Name="ChatRow1" Width="200" Margin="10,10,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

            <StackPanel x:Name="ChatRow2" Width="200" Margin="0,10,10,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </Grid>

    </ScrollViewer>
```

Then when adding a message I make a Border, then make a TextBlock. I then add the textblock to the border and then add the border to the corresponding stackpanel.

I then attempt to get the height of the TextBlock (or the Border, same thing happens with both) and make 2 Separators of 0 opacity. One of height 10 to add to the panel the message was added to, and one that's meant to be textBlockHeight + 10 to the panel where nothing was added.

```
public void PrintOwnMessage(string msg)
{

    var border = new Border()
    {
        Margin = new Thickness(0),
        Padding = new Thickness(10,0,0,0),
        BorderThickness = new Thickness(1),
        BorderBrush = Brushes.White,
        Background = Brushes.Azure,
        CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(5)
    };
    var textBlock = new TextBlock()
    {
        Text = msg,
        FontSize = 20,
        TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap


    };
    Console.WriteLine(border.DesiredSize);
    border.Child = textBlock;
    //panel[0] is the rightside panel where this function adds the message to
    panel[0].Children.Add(border);
    msgHeight = textBlock.ActualHeight;
    textBlock.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
    var desiredSizeNew = textBlock.DesiredSize;
    msgHeight = desiredSizeNew.Height + 10;
    panel[0].Children.Add(new Separator() { Opacity = 0, Height = 10});
    panel[1].Children.Add(new Separator() { Opacity = 0, Height = msgHeight });
    scrl.ScrollToEnd();
}
```

---

**The problem:**

The "desiredSizeNew" var seems to be the same everytime. Note that I'm getting the size this way because trying to get .Height gives me a NaN and .ActualHeight always returns a zero.

It always gives me the size of one line ("26.6") even if the message wraps to multiple lines, so the code works as long as the messages are only 1 line of height.

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I hope I was able to explain my problem well enough. This is my first time making anything with c# so any suggestions on a better way to go about achieving what I want would be great. Although I would like to know how to solve this first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer to the point *"any suggestions on a better way to go about achieving what I want would be great"*.

I think you should try using DataTemplate. Creating elements in the code behind often end up badly (lot of work around, unused parts, buggy behaviors, etc.).

I based my example on DataTemplate and two simple classes:

```
public class Message
{
    public string content { get; set; }
    public Message(string content)
    {
        this.content = content;
    }
}

public class MsgSent:Message
{
    public MsgSent(string content) : base(content) { }
}
public class MsgRecieved : Message
{
    public MsgRecieved(string content) : base(content) { }
}
```

The `MsgSent` and `MsgRecieved` are totally similar. But we can imagine different behaviors in your chat. And most of all, I need two different classes for the DataTemplate.

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="viewChat" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MsgRecieved}">
                <Border  Background="LightGreen" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" CornerRadius="5" Margin="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding content}" Margin="5"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MsgSent}">
                <Border  Background="LightBlue" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" CornerRadius="5" Margin="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding content}" Margin="5"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
    </ListView>
```

I wrote two `DataTemplate` based on the two previous classes. They are quite similiar, but you can do what you want and customize them. If the common code on `DataTemplate` becomes huge, you can regroup it in a `Style` resource.

Here is the code behind to fill your chat:

```
ObservableCollection<Message> letsChat = new ObservableCollection<Message>();
letsChat.Add(new MsgRecieved("Hello world! \nHow are you?"));
letsChat.Add(new MsgSent("Hi, good to see you!"));
letsChat.Add(new MsgSent("Hey, are you still there?"));
letsChat.Add(new MsgSent("Please let me know when you are back."));
letsChat.Add(new MsgRecieved("Hello world! \nHow are you?"));

viewChat.DataContext = letsChat;
```

I used an ObservableCollection so you can fill it dynamically.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is great and so much simpler than what i was doing :D

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, `DesiredSize` isn't the `ActualHeight`, and until WPF has been through its measure and arrange process, that won't have the final values.

But you wouldn't want to do it this way anyway, because there would be nothing stopping those values from changing. For example, if the screen was rotated then the widths might change, which would alter the wrapping, which would change the actual height...which would mean that the calculated height which was set as the height of the placeholder is now wrong.

You're trying to micromanage the layout. Let WPF do that for you. Laying things out is WPF's job, and it is *very* good at it. But you have to describe the layout properly. Once you've done that, WPF will take care of adjusting things when things change. If you find yourself trying to set Widths or Heights, you usually need to think harder about the layout. There are times you have to do it, but it should be *rare*.

Basically you have defined two `StackPanel`s side by side. Each time a message is added to one side you add a separator underneath, and you are trying to manually keep the other one in step by placing a corresponding tall separator.

If you place the items for both sides in a single `StackPanel` (rather than having two) then it would sort out the vertical alignment for you. Then you could left align the messages for the left, and right align the messages for the right. As an added bonus, this means that both sides have more width to play with. But if you don't like that, you could limit the `MaxWidth` of the `TextBlock`s.

I would also strongly suggest you look into using MVVM and Binding rather than manually creating controls in code behind. Again, this will take you away from micromanaging things that you don't need to.

Comment: Thank you! I had never heard of MVVM I'm reading on that now.